# How to pass Object as a parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, extjs4.1

I want to pass Object in function. Here is my code

```
var hyperLinkObj = new Object();
hyperLinkObj.path="abc";
hyperLinkObj.text="abctext";

'<li><a href="#" onclick="onItemClick(hyperLinkObj)">'+description+'</a></li>'
```

Here I am creating Object called as "hyperLinkObj" Now I am creating "li" tag and putting hyperlink in li Now When I inspect the I am getting something like

```
'<li><a href="#" onclick="onItemClick([object Object])">'+description+'</a></li>'
```

So How can I pass the hyperLinkObject , as in the onItemClick I have do many thing on this Object.

See Actually I wanted to do something like this.

1] There is an Object which has many Category
   So wanted to loop through it.
2] then on Each category item click wanted to call OnItemClcik with hyperLinkObj
3] Then on click of on Hyperlink , wanted to do operation like fetching Hyperlink.path and show the Breadcrumb.
4] and finally I am using Extjs 
   So Ext.Panel.update("Li text");

May be I didnt mentioned that ExtJs.update.. it is not working as per your suggestion..

Can you explain How can I achive this ?

Comment: What is the object supposed to reference in relationship to the clicked list item?

Comment: `var hyperLinkObj = { path: "abc", text: "abctext" };` Preferred syntax for objects.

Comment: Where is hyperLinkObj created? Global scope? Can you show how you intend to use it in the onItemClick function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `hyperLinkObj` in global scope, and refer to it in the onclick.

```
hyperLinkObj = new Object();
hyperLinkObj.path="abc";
hyperLinkObj.text="abctext";
Ext.Panel.update('<li><a href="#" onclick=\'onItemClick({path:"'+hyperLinkObj.path+'",text:"'+hyperLinkObj.text+'"})\'>'+description+'</a></li>')
```

`[object Object]` is the `toString()` of an `Object()`, and contains no details.

Comment: I cant use the Global object as It will be in loop., I have explain the senario above

Answer (score -1):

use binding events for complex onclick functionality:

```
document.getElementById('anchorID').onclick=function(){/* some code */}
```

it will be easier for you.
check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/amedr/

Comment: dunno :/ but if you think that is good answer, vote up please.

Comment: Well...  I'm not going to upvote for the sake of cancelling theirs.  I don't consider your answer good either though, because it's not complete in a sense enough for the poster to use, I only upvote good complete answers.  I mostly just want to know why the down-voter considered it bad because the idea behind your answer is a correct one.